# MySQL return fields and data from a join with table name?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in mysql to return the tablename.field in a join without manually setting the 'AS' ? For instance, let's pretend I'd like to run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

What i'd like to obtain is something like

```
table1.prop1 = 'some value'
table1.prop2 = 'some value'
table2.prop1 = 'some value'
...
```

Possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not according to the SQL spec.  You can, however, build a udf or other higher language function to do this for you...